# Opera 11 - prevent panels/tabs opening when examining RSS feeds

Tags: opera

I've reviewed the suggested questions, based on my title, so apologies if I'm going over old ground.

Opera 11 recently came out. Whilst I use it as my RSS aggregator, I don't use it for any other messaging purposes. So I'm annoyed with, whenever I open Feeds->Read Feeds, I suddenly get the panels side menu, and the Mail panel opened automatically. This is new behaviour from the 10.x series, and I can't seem to find an option to turn it off. When I go to "Read Feeds", I just want the feeds window to open. That's it.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about just toggling F4?

Comment: @random - yes, I can hide the panel. Every time. But in v 10.0 (IIRC), reading the feeds on a full width screen was Feeds -> Read Feeds. Then they introduced the single "Menu" menu at top left, and it was now 3 clicks to get to the same position (okay, it freed up a bit of vertical space to have the "Menu" menu, so not complaining too much). Now, it's turned into 4 clicks (or 3 clicks + F4). I'm just trying to retain some sanity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the "Auto Mail Panel Toggle" setting in `opera:config`, which by switching it off, prevents this annoying behaviour. I found this in opera 11.50, not sure if it existed in previous versions and I was just too dense to find it.